# List View Web part not showing all available views for list

Tags: 2013, web-part, list-view, web

We have added a list view web part to a page, and we get the `Current View` link in the web part. Which is configurable when modifying the actual web part.

What we'd like to see (instead of having to click the ellipses button/context menu to get the other views) is the views displayed horizontally like when you are viewing the list itself.

When viewing the list itself, we see `All Items` `View 1` `View 2`, etc.

Is this possible in the list view web part to display all available views in a horizontal/breadcrumb layout?  Please advise.

Trying this in simple webpart code snippet to get back all views:

```
<script>
var viewCollection = null;
    function runCode() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var web = clientContext.get_web();

            var listCollection = web.get_lists();
            var list = listCollection.getByTitle("MyListName");
            this.viewCollection = list.get_views();

            //var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation();
            //viewInfo.set_title('MyView');
            //this.viewCollection.add(viewInfo);

            clientContext.load(this.viewCollection);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var viewInfo = 'Tasks list current views: \n\n';
        var viewEnumerator = this.viewCollection.getEnumerator();
        while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
            viewInfo += view.get_title() + '\n';
        }
        alert(viewInfo);
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
<a onclick='return runCode();'>Click here</a>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use a `Content Editor` web-part on top of the list view web-part. Then format it as per your wish.

Comment: I don't need to format any columns, I just want to show all the views

Comment: Formatting in the sense of how you want to display the `View` URL's.

Comment: I can see it's the span class ms-pivotControl-container, but in when viewing the list, more anchor tags are available than with the list view web part from the home page

Comment: Have you tried to edit the web part properties? Scroll down to miscellaneous options and in there is a check box for view selector.

Comment: There's the "Disable view selector menu", but it is un-checked

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SharePoint 2013 I would recommend you to consider the following approach. In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a so called `Client Rendering Mode (CSR)` which is intended for rendering of List Views and Forms using HTML and JavaScript and which is a *default rendering mode*.

**About View selector menu**

`ClientPivotControl` control (`clienttemplates.js`) is intended for rendering *View selector menu*, `SurfacedPivotCount` property defines the amount of view menu options rendered horizontally (default value is `3`)

### How to display all view options using CSR

The following template demonstrates how to override `SurfacedPivotCount` property in order to display *all view menu options*:

```
function renderHeaderTemplateWithAllViewsMenu(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
    var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = viewData.length -2; //display all View options except 'Create View' & 'Modify View'   
    return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames); //render default Header template
}

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
    Header: renderHeaderTemplateWithAllViewsMenu
  }
});
```

### How to apply the changes

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Using [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx) of XLV web part
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page (`NewForm.aspx`) into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

### Result

Assume a `Workflow Tasks` list and all view menu options should be rendered. After applying the corresponding JavaScript template the List View will be rendered as shown on picture below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Vadim.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I'm working with a default.aspx page, as it's the home page for the site collection.  We have numerous listview web parts on this page, and if I try the JS, I get:    TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but why not add a list view web part for each view and use a simple JavaScript to hide or show only the views you are interested in seeing. If this sounds like a solution for you leave a comment and I will send you or post here a script I wrote that simulates tabs for the list view web parts on a page.