# Add custom style for library views

Tags: list-view, library, style.css

We set up multiple views on our libraries.  Is there a way to style these so it's more obvious for the users?  I looked for css but couldn't find anything that relates to the library views.  Thanks in advance for your help!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is the way to go.

If you inspect the html you can find a couple classes to get you started.

```
/*regular item*/
.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt{}

/*selected item*/
.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt-selected{}
```

For more on the view selector, you take a look at some JavaScript customizations as well:

[List View Web part not showing all available views for list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126234/list-view-web-part-not-showing-all-available-views-for-list)